# How to do cancel in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to cancel the mail instead of asking the user Save draft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - as far as I know, it's not possible as it's handled by the mail composer.

Comment: What is the reason of Save or Delete Draft? Is the user could get the saved draft in later time?

Comment: Yes, you could choose simply to save the email you were composing to finish or send later on.  That's why you have the Save option.  And obviously the Delete Draft will delete the email you were composing entirely.